# Rename default value of 'none' in custom option?

Tags: magento-1.9

Just want to rename the default value of 'none' to something different in a set of radio buttons for custom options. I'm assuming this has to be edited in a core file. I'm ok with it being site wide. any help?

As of right now, i want the custom option to be optional/not required for a product. But 'none' shows up among my choices. Once I go to required, none goes away. So, I just want to change 'none' to say 'no preference'.

Magento 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If want to change just label you can add in translation. go to file

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
```

search word None and add no preference on second column